# Json_decode with special chars

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I got a big problem posting data via jQuery Ajax as JSON to my Server. JSLint say the data is OK and the Content-Type of the request is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. Server runs on PHP 5.2.11 so I can't use `json_last_error()`.

I tried url_decode, utf8_decode and html_entities_decode, but nothing seems to work.

`var_dump(json_decode($jdata));` returns null, but if I do a `var_dump($jdata)` everything looks OK. `$jdata` is the post data:`$jdata = $this->input->post('requestdata');`.

Here some example post data grab from Firebug:

```
{
    "projectnumber": "345",
    "projecdescription": "345",
    "articles": [
        {
            "position": 1,
            "article_id": 677,
            "online_text": "3 Behälter; Band I-III nach indiv. Stückliste, Sprache: DE - Sprache: de"
        },
        {
            "position": 2,
            "article_id": 678,
            "online_text": "2 Behälter; Band I-III nach indiv. Stückliste, Sprache: ### - Sprache: en"
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit:

I tried this now:

```
$string = $this->input->post('requestdata');
var_dump($string);
$json = preg_replace('/,\s*([\]}])/m', '$1', utf8_encode($string));
$json = json_decode($json);
var_dump($json);
```

The result is:

> string(338) "{"projectnumber": "4444", "projecdescription": "4444", "articles": [{"position":1, "article_id": 676, "online_text": "### Behälter; Band I-III nach indiv. Stückliste, Sprache: DE 
>    - Sprache: de"}, {"position":2, "article_id": 681, "online_text": "### Behälter; Band I-III nach indiv. Stückliste, Sprache: ### 
>    - Sprache: en"}]}"
>   NULL

By pasting the JSON string direct into the PHP source it works, but getting it from post not!

Comment: This would work for you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12884807/1226894

Comment: possible duplicate of [json\_decode is returning null in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884802/json-decode-is-returning-null-in-php)

Comment: Are you sure that you have an UTF8 string on the server-side? Try `var_dump(json_decode(utf8_encode($jdata)));`

Comment: See live demo : http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZWZf0I

Comment: remove the utf8_encode and it works, ur php file is already utf8, so you are double-encoding

Comment: @Baba I've edited my first post above trying your example!

Comment: You add new line issue ... see answer below

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are having error because of new line in your string

```
$string = '{"projectnumber" : "4444","projecdescription" : "4444", "articles" : [{"position":1, "article_id" : 676, "online_text" : "### Behälter; Band I-III nach indiv. Stückliste, Sprache: DE 
 - Sprache: de"},{"position":2, "article_id" : 681, "online_text" : "### Behälter; Band I-III nach indiv. Stückliste, Sprache: ### 
 - Sprache: en"}]}';


$string = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", " ", $string);
$json = utf8_encode($string);
$json = json_decode($json);
var_dump($json);
```

Output

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'projectnumber' => string '4444' (length=4)
  public 'projecdescription' => string '4444' (length=4)
  public 'articles' => 
    array
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[2]
          public 'position' => int 1
          public 'article_id' => int 676
          public 'online_text' => string '### BehÃ¤lter; Band I-III nach indiv. StÃ¼ckliste, Sprache: DE   - Sprache: de' (length=78)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[3]
          public 'position' => int 2
          public 'article_id' => int 681
          public 'online_text' => string '### BehÃ¤lter; Band I-III nach indiv. StÃ¼ckliste, Sprache: ###   - Sprache: en' (length=79)
```

Answer (score 13):

Voting for the newline too

json_decode_nice + keep linebreaks:

```
function json_decode_nice($json, $assoc = TRUE){
    $json = str_replace("\n","\\n",$json);
    $json = str_replace("\r","",$json);
    $json = preg_replace('/([{,]+)(\s*)([^"]+?)\s*:/','$1"$3":',$json);
    $json = preg_replace('/(,)\s*}$/','}',$json);
    return json_decode($json,$assoc);
}
```

If you want to keep the linebreaks just escape the slash.

You don't need utf-8 encode, if everything is set to utf-8 (header, db connection, etc)

Comment: Don't forget to include \t in the list of naughty characters.  This only seems to be a problem for PHP < 5.4.

Comment: @Hafenkranich tk bro

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", " ", $string);
$json = utf8_encode($string);
$json = json_decode($json);
var_dump($json);
```