# decode json string with long string (morethan 1000 chars) containing + symbol in php

Tags: php, json

I had a json string containing special characters like +, -, ", '. when i am trying to use json_decode for the string, the decoding is breaking at + symbol. What ever the content after + symbol is not decoded.

my code as follows:

```
//Example string
$str = '{"image":"wo7898Ee/fp+18mtyeex//Z"}';
$res = json_decode($str, true);
```

My Output is printing till /fp. The last chars are getting truncated and showing decoded output as ...

Please help

Comment: You try to json_decode a string?

Comment: Your string is not formatted as a [JSON](https://www.json.org/) object, and therefore cannot be decoded using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)...

Comment: *My Output is printing till /fp.* - the code you've posted doesn't generate any output, so I don't know how you're seeing anything at all

Comment: Your code should work. Check my answer as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/12911536/3973463

Comment: @pr1nc3, In my case, it ia very long string contains morethan 1000 characters. So, it is getting truncated at the last. not showing total decoded output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json\_decode with special chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911536/json-decode-with-special-chars)

Comment: @Alfredo A, Please read my question carefully. Thanks

Comment: @sree People have read your question carefully, but there's no code in it that causes the issue you're describing. If you want help, we need to be able to replicate the issue. You say your output is being truncated, but you haven't shown us how you're generating any output. You say your actual string is more than 1000 characters, but the one in the question works correctly.

Comment: @sree you're going to have to show us an example which actually reproduces your issue. 1000 characters isn't really all that long, tbh. It's hard to see how that's affecting it, but if you can demo it to us, then we can take it seriously. You could also try running [json_last_error_msg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) to see if the encoder reports any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = '{
    "image": "wo7898Ee/fp+18mtyeex//Z"
}';
$res = json_decode($str, true);

print_r($res['image']);
```

Let's say that this is your json. A valid one. Then you can use json_decode and can expect an output. Json decode is used (like the function name states) to decode a valid json.

The output is : `wo7898Ee/fp+18mtyeex//Z`

Comment: In my case, it ia very long string contains morethan 1000 characters. So, it is getting truncated at the last. not showing total decoded output.

Comment: Could you provide a sample? i am pretty sure that json_decode does not "trim" anything. Also did you try to print_r your new array to see if this is actually the case?