# How to display special character in json_decode() in php like "Ñ"

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

I want to display the name from the database but the name contains "Ñ" and it results "Null"

I'm using this code

```
    $result = array();

    $sth = $dbcon->prepare("MY SELECT CODE HERE");
    $sth->execute();
            while($row_count = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $result[] = $row_count;
            }
    echo json_encode($result);
```

And here is the result.. as you can see the null in name because of the "Ñ" cuz this string has and Ñ in the table

[{"emp_id":"12561-2013","name":null,"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911536/json-decode-with-special-chars
Try above solution may be it works

Answer (score 0):

Use json_encode with JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE flag, ie., 
`json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

Comment: im using this echo json_encode($result,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); but it results "null"

Comment: Your mysql character set is probably not UTF-8. Can you try doing `utf8_encode` before doing a `json_encode` ? Like, `echo json_encode(utf_encode($result));`

Comment: @CalabDonss As shared above, please try: `echo json_encode(utf_encode($result));`